# Logarithm math operation in Solidity

Tags: solidity

what is the most efficient way to compute a logarithm in solidity? Is there a library that implements it or a built in function?

Comment: Check this library: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L402

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though there's no current implementation (and I couldn't see one in the [dapp-bin](https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin) either), you could implement your own using a [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Derivative.2C_Taylor_series), as suggested by Vitalik in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/253ymf/could_contracts_including_logarithms_be/) old Reddit thread.

For the example in the thread, it effectively comes down to something like the following:

```
 x = msg.data[0]
 LOG = 0
 while x >= 1500000:
     LOG = LOG + 405465
     x = x * 2 / 3
 x = x - 1000000
 y = x
 i = 1
 while i < 10:
      LOG = LOG + (y / i)
      i = i + 1
      y = y * x / 1000000
      LOG = LOG - (y / i)
      i = i + 1
      y = y * x / 1000000
return(LOG)
```

Bear in mind the number of steps and the associated gas cost...

Answer (score 18):

Here's a very efficient (< 700 gas) way to calculate the ceiling of log_2:

```
function log2(uint x) returns (uint y){
   assembly {
        let arg := x
        x := sub(x,1)
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x02))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x04))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x10))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x100))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x10000))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x100000000))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x10000000000000000))
        x := or(x, div(x, 0x100000000000000000000000000000000))
        x := add(x, 1)
        let m := mload(0x40)
        mstore(m,           0xf8f9cbfae6cc78fbefe7cdc3a1793dfcf4f0e8bbd8cec470b6a28a7a5a3e1efd)
        mstore(add(m,0x20), 0xf5ecf1b3e9debc68e1d9cfabc5997135bfb7a7a3938b7b606b5b4b3f2f1f0ffe)
        mstore(add(m,0x40), 0xf6e4ed9ff2d6b458eadcdf97bd91692de2d4da8fd2d0ac50c6ae9a8272523616)
        mstore(add(m,0x60), 0xc8c0b887b0a8a4489c948c7f847c6125746c645c544c444038302820181008ff)
        mstore(add(m,0x80), 0xf7cae577eec2a03cf3bad76fb589591debb2dd67e0aa9834bea6925f6a4a2e0e)
        mstore(add(m,0xa0), 0xe39ed557db96902cd38ed14fad815115c786af479b7e83247363534337271707)
        mstore(add(m,0xc0), 0xc976c13bb96e881cb166a933a55e490d9d56952b8d4e801485467d2362422606)
        mstore(add(m,0xe0), 0x753a6d1b65325d0c552a4d1345224105391a310b29122104190a110309020100)
        mstore(0x40, add(m, 0x100))
        let magic := 0x818283848586878898a8b8c8d8e8f929395969799a9b9d9e9faaeb6bedeeff
        let shift := 0x100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        let a := div(mul(x, magic), shift)
        y := div(mload(add(m,sub(255,a))), shift)
        y := add(y, mul(256, gt(arg, 0x8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)))
    }  
}
```

EDIT: Since this seems like magic... It's just the technique given [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogDeBruijn)

The first section clears all but the highest set bit. `magic` is a de Bruijn sequence with `n = 8`. Clearing all but the highest bit of `x` turns it into essentially a left shift (actually, I could have saved a couple multiplications by doing right shifts instead). This shift then defines a unique `8` bit sequence which we use as an index into the lookup table (defined by all the `mstore`s)

The last line just deals with an overflow case.

Comment: please explain!

Answer (score 7):

Here is high-precision ln(x) implementation for 128.128 fixed point numbers:

```
/**
 * 2^127.
 */
uint128 private constant TWO127 = 0x80000000000000000000000000000000;

/**
 * 2^128 - 1.
 */
uint128 private constant TWO128_1 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

/**
 * ln(2) * 2^128.
 */
uint128 private constant LN2 = 0xb17217f7d1cf79abc9e3b39803f2f6af;

/**
 * Return index of most significant non-zero bit in given non-zero 256-bit
 * unsigned integer value.
 *
 * @param x value to get index of most significant non-zero bit in
 * @return index of most significant non-zero bit in given number
 */
function mostSignificantBit (uint256 x) pure internal returns (uint8 r) {
  require (x > 0);

  if (x >= 0x100000000000000000000000000000000) {x >>= 128; r += 128;}
  if (x >= 0x10000000000000000) {x >>= 64; r += 64;}
  if (x >= 0x100000000) {x >>= 32; r += 32;}
  if (x >= 0x10000) {x >>= 16; r += 16;}
  if (x >= 0x100) {x >>= 8; r += 8;}
  if (x >= 0x10) {x >>= 4; r += 4;}
  if (x >= 0x4) {x >>= 2; r += 2;}
  if (x >= 0x2) r += 1; // No need to shift x anymore
}
/*
function mostSignificantBit (uint256 x) pure internal returns (uint8) {
  require (x > 0);

  uint8 l = 0;
  uint8 h = 255;

  while (h > l) {
    uint8 m = uint8 ((uint16 (l) + uint16 (h)) >> 1);
    uint256 t = x >> m;
    if (t == 0) h = m - 1;
    else if (t > 1) l = m + 1;
    else return m;
  }

  return h;
}
*/

/**
 * Calculate log_2 (x / 2^128) * 2^128.
 *
 * @param x parameter value
 * @return log_2 (x / 2^128) * 2^128
 */
function log_2 (uint256 x) pure internal returns (int256) {
  require (x > 0);

  uint8 msb = mostSignificantBit (x);

  if (msb > 128) x >>= msb - 128;
  else if (msb < 128) x <<= 128 - msb;

  x &= TWO128_1;

  int256 result = (int256 (msb) - 128) << 128; // Integer part of log_2

  int256 bit = TWO127;
  for (uint8 i = 0; i < 128 && x > 0; i++) {
    x = (x << 1) + ((x * x + TWO127) >> 128);
    if (x > TWO128_1) {
      result |= bit;
      x = (x >> 1) - TWO127;
    }
    bit >>= 1;
  }

  return result;
}

/**
 * Calculate ln (x / 2^128) * 2^128.
 *
 * @param x parameter value
 * @return ln (x / 2^128) * 2^128
 */
function ln (uint256 x) pure internal returns (int256) {
  require (x > 0);

  int256 l2 = log_2 (x);
  if (l2 == 0) return 0;
  else {
    uint256 al2 = uint256 (l2 > 0 ? l2 : -l2);
    uint8 msb = mostSignificantBit (al2);
    if (msb > 127) al2 >>= msb - 127;
    al2 = (al2 * LN2 + TWO127) >> 128;
    if (msb > 127) al2 <<= msb - 127;

    return int256 (l2 >= 0 ? al2 : -al2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Optimized `mostSignificantBit` to achieve 4x improvement on `log2` call: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/73682/3032

Comment: Are you sure that `log2(x) == log2(x*2^128)/2^128`? It seems it is wrong assumption.

Comment: We found your latest implementation for 64.64 fixed point: https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol#L366, and optimized it from 10K gas to 4K gas by reducing precision to `1e6`: https://gist.github.com/k06a/af6c58fe6634e48e53929451877eb5b5

Comment: `log2(x) == log2(x*2^128)/2^128` seems to be wrong assumption, but where did I assume this?  Function `log_2` does not calculate `log2 (x)`, but rather `log2 (x / 2^128) * 2^128`.

Comment: in comment to the method

Comment: Function `log_2` treats integer argument `x` as a numerator of simple fraction with denominator `2^128`, calculates 2-based logarithm of this fraction, converts result to a simple fraction with denominator `2^128`, and returns numerator of this fraction.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov can you please look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113844/how-does-uniswap-v3s-logarithm-library-work ? Trying to understand Uniswap's optimizations for arbitrary base logs.

Answer (score 5):

My advanced math library [PRBMath](https://github.com/paulrberg/prb-math) offers `log2` (binary logarithm), `ln` (natural logarithm) and `log10` (common logarithm). I'm gonna paste my implementations here, for posterity, but check out the linked repo for the most up-to-date code.

### Log2

Gas efficiency: min 377, max 7241, avg 4243. This seems to be faster than the solution posted by Mikhail Vladimirov.

```
/// @notice Finds the zero-based index of the first one in the binary representation of x.
/// @dev See the note on msb in the "Find First Set" Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set
/// @param x The uint256 number for which to find the index of the most significant bit.
/// @return msb The index of the most significant bit as an uint256.
function mostSignificantBit(uint256 x) internal pure returns (uint256 msb) {
    if (x >= 2**128) {
        x >>= 128;
        msb += 128;
    }
    if (x >= 2**64) {
        x >>= 64;
        msb += 64;
    }
    if (x >= 2**32) {
        x >>= 32;
        msb += 32;
    }
    if (x >= 2**16) {
        x >>= 16;
        msb += 16;
    }
    if (x >= 2**8) {
        x >>= 8;
        msb += 8;
    }
    if (x >= 2**4) {
        x >>= 4;
        msb += 4;
    }
    if (x >= 2**2) {
        x >>= 2;
        msb += 2;
    }
    if (x >= 2**1) {
        // No need to shift x any more.
        msb += 1;
    }
}
/// @notice Calculates the binary logarithm of x.
///
/// @dev Based on the iterative approximation algorithm.
/// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm#Iterative_approximation
///
/// Requirements:
/// - x must be greater than zero.
///
/// Caveats:
/// - The results are nor perfectly accurate to the last digit, due to the lossy precision of the iterative approximation.
///
/// @param x The signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number for which to calculate the binary logarithm.
/// @return result The binary logarithm as a signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number.
function log2(int256 x) internal pure returns (int256 result) {
    require(x > 0);
    unchecked {
        // This works because log2(x) = -log2(1/x).
        int256 sign;
        if (x >= SCALE) {
            sign = 1;
        } else {
            sign = -1;
            // Do the fixed-point inversion inline to save gas. The numerator is SCALE * SCALE.
            assembly {
                x := div(1000000000000000000000000000000000000, x)
            }
        }

        // Calculate the integer part of the logarithm and add it to the result and finally calculate y = x * 2^(-n).
        uint256 n = mostSignificantBit(uint256(x / SCALE));

        // The integer part of the logarithm as a signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number. The operation can't overflow
        // because n is maximum 255, SCALE is 1e18 and sign is either 1 or -1.
        result = int256(n) * SCALE;

        // This is y = x * 2^(-n).
        int256 y = x >> n;

        // If y = 1, the fractional part is zero.
        if (y == SCALE) {
            return result * sign;
        }

        // Calculate the fractional part via the iterative approximation.
        // The "delta >>= 1" part is equivalent to "delta /= 2", but shifting bits is faster.
        for (int256 delta = int256(HALF_SCALE); delta > 0; delta >>= 1) {
            y = (y * y) / SCALE;

            // Is y^2 > 2 and so in the range [2,4)?
            if (y >= 2 * SCALE) {
                // Add the 2^(-m) factor to the logarithm.
                result += delta;

                // Corresponds to z/2 on Wikipedia.
                y >>= 1;
            }
        }
        result *= sign;
    }
}
```

### Ln

Gas efficiency: min 463, max 7241, avg 4243.

```
/// @notice Calculates the natural logarithm of x.
///
/// @dev Based on the insight that ln(x) = log2(x) / log2(e).
///
/// Requirements:
/// - All from "log2".
///
/// Caveats:
/// - All from "log2".
/// - This doesn't return exactly 1 for 2718281828459045235, for that we would need more fine-grained precision.
///
/// @param x The signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number for which to calculate the natural logarithm.
/// @return result The natural logarithm as a signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number.
function ln(int256 x) internal pure returns (int256 result) {
    // Do the fixed-point multiplication inline to save gas. This is overflow-safe because the maximum value that log2(x)
    // can return is 195205294292027477728.
    unchecked { result = (log2(x) * SCALE) / LOG2_E; }
}
```

### Log10

Gas efficiency: min 104, max 9074, avg 4337.

```
/// @notice Calculates the common logarithm of x.
///
/// @dev First checks if x is an exact power of ten and it stops if yes. If it's not, calculates the common
/// logarithm based on the insight that log10(x) = log2(x) / log2(10).
///
/// Requirements:
/// - All from "log2".
///
/// Caveats:
/// - All from "log2".
///
/// @param x The signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number for which to calculate the common logarithm.
/// @return result The common logarithm as a signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point number.
function log10(int256 x) internal pure returns (int256 result) {
    require(x > 0);

    // Note that the "mul" in this block is the assembly mul operation, not the "mul" function defined in this contract.
    // prettier-ignore
    assembly {
        switch x
        case 1 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(0, 18)) }
        case 10 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(1, 18)) }
        case 100 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(2, 18)) }
        case 1000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(3, 18)) }
        case 10000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(4, 18)) }
        case 100000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(5, 18)) }
        case 1000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(6, 18)) }
        case 10000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(7, 18)) }
        case 100000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(8, 18)) }
        case 1000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(9, 18)) }
        case 10000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(10, 18)) }
        case 100000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(11, 18)) }
        case 1000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(12, 18)) }
        case 10000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(13, 18)) }
        case 100000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(14, 18)) }
        case 1000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(15, 18)) }
        case 10000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(16, 18)) }
        case 100000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, sub(17, 18)) }
        case 1000000000000000000 { result := 0 }
        case 10000000000000000000 { result := SCALE }
        case 100000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 2) }
        case 1000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 3) }
        case 10000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 4) }
        case 100000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 5) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 6) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 7) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 8) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 9) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 10) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 11) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 12) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 13) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 14) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 15) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 16) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 17) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 18) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 19) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 20) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 21) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 22) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 23) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 24) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 25) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 26) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 27) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 28) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 29) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 30) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 31) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 32) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 33) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 34) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 35) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 36) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 37) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 38) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 39) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 40) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 41) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 42) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 43) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 44) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 45) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 46) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 47) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 48) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 49) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 50) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 51) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 52) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 53) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 54) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 55) }
        case 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 56) }
        case 1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 57) }
        case 10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 { result := mul(SCALE, 58) }
        default {
            result := MAX_SD59x18
        }
    }

    if (result == MAX_SD59x18) {
        // Do the fixed-point division inline to save gas. The denominator is log2(10).
        unchecked { result = (log2(x) * SCALE) / 332192809488736234; }
    }
}
```

### Notes

The functions above assume the signed 59.18-decimal fixed-point representation (succinctly written as SD59x18), which are integer numbers that emulate fixed-point by considering the last 18 digits the first 18 decimals. For example, `e` is written as 2718281828459045235.

#### Constants Used

- SCALE = 1e18
- HALF_SCALE = 5e17
- LOG2_E = 1442695040888963407
- MAX_SD59x18 = 57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967

Answer (score 1):

Compute the largest integer smaller than or equal to the binary logarithm of a given input:

```
uint256 constant ONE = 1;

function floorLog(uint256 n) pure returns (uint8) {
    uint8 res = 0;

    if (n < 256) {
        // At most 8 iterations
        while (n > 1) {
            n >>= 1;
            res += 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Exactly 8 iterations
        for (uint8 s = 128; s > 0; s >>= 1) {
            if (n >= (ONE << s)) {
                n >>= s;
                res |= s;
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

---

Compute the binary logarithm of a given input scaled up by `PRECISION` bits:

```
uint8 constant PRECISION = 127;
uint256 constant FIXED_1 = 0x080000000000000000000000000000000; // (1<<(PRECISION)
uint256 constant FIXED_2 = 0x100000000000000000000000000000000; // (2<<(PRECISION)
uint256 constant MAX_NUM = 0x1ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff; // (1<<(256-PRECISION))-1

function log(uint256 numerator, uint256 denominator) pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 res = 0;

    assert(numerator <= MAX_NUM);
    uint256 x = numerator * FIXED_1 / denominator;

    // If x >= 2, then we compute the integer part of log2(x), which is larger than 0.
    if (x >= FIXED_2) {
        uint8 count = floorLog(x / FIXED_1);
        x >>= count; // now x < 2
        res = count * FIXED_1;
    }

    // If x > 1, then we compute the fraction part of log2(x), which is larger than 0.
    if (x > FIXED_1) {
        for (uint8 i = PRECISION; i > 0; --i) {
            x = (x * x) / FIXED_1; // now 1 < x < 4
            if (x >= FIXED_2) {
                x >>= 1; // now 1 < x < 2
                res += ONE << (i - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

A few notes on the function above:

- It returns `floor(log(numerator/denominator)*2^PRECISION)`
- Both input values must range between `1` and `2^(256-PRECISION)-1`
- The output value ranges between `0` and `floor(log(2^(256-PRECISION)-1)*2^PRECISION)`
- It assumes `numerator >= denominator`, because the output would be negative otherwise

---

Compute the natural logarithm of a given input scaled up to `PRECISION` bits:

```
uint256 private constant LOG_NUMERATOR   = 0x3f80fe03f80fe03f80fe03f80fe03f8;
uint256 private constant LOG_DENOMINATOR = 0x5b9de1d10bf4103d647b0955897ba80;
function ln(uint256 numerator, uint256 denominator) pure returns (uint256) {
    return log(numerator, denominator) * LOG_NUMERATOR / LOG_DENOMINATOR;
}
```

---

Note that all the constant values above should be computed according to the value of `PRECISION`.

If you right-shift the result by `PRECISION` bits, then you get a rough (integer) approximation.

If you divide it by `2 ^ PRECISION` on a calculator, then you get a much better approximation.

The maximum value of `PRECISION` safe for use is `127`.

Answer (score 0):

I was interested in a 2log:
So the first one does do practically the same thing as above.
But the other does binary search in the logarithmic value in [0,256].
The gas cost of the latter is very constant. The gas cost of the first seems pretty linear to the output.
The best would be to do binary search up to a certain precision and then finishing with the simple searching probably.

```
    function findLogSimple(uint b) returns (uint){
        for(uint i=0;2**i<=b;i++){}
        return i-1;
    }
    function findLogBinarySearch(uint b) returns (uint){
        uint up = 256;
        uint down = 0;
        uint attempt = (up+down)/2;
        while (up>down+1){
            if(b>=(2**attempt)){
                down=attempt;
            }else{
                up=attempt;
            }
            attempt=(up+down)/2;
        }
        return attempt;
    }
```

And even slightly better is a mixture of the two:

```
function findLogMix(uint b) returns (uint){
    //if(b==0){return 0;}
    uint up = 256;
    uint down = 0;
    uint attempt = (up+down)/2;
    while (up>down+4){
        if(b>=(2**attempt)){
            down=attempt;
        }else{
            up=attempt;
        }
        attempt=(up+down)/2;
    }
uint temp = 2**down;
while(temp<=b){
    down++;
    temp=temp*2;
}
return down;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A fast and branch-free implementation to compute ceiling of log2. Translated from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272424/compute-fast-log-base-2-ceiling

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;


library MathUtil {
  function ceilLog2(uint _x) pure internal returns(uint) {
    require(_x > 0);

    uint x = _x;
    uint y = (((x & (x - 1)) == 0) ? 0 : 1);
    uint j = 128;
    uint k = 0;

    k = (((x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF00000000000000000000000000000000) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0x00000000FFFF0000) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0x000000000000FF00) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0x00000000000000F0) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0x000000000000000C) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    k = (((x & 0x0000000000000002) == 0) ? 0 : j);
    y += k;
    x >>= k;
    j >>= 1;

    return y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gives `0` instead of `255` for `0x80b20f6c0271cf198d45a6b3b25e59e60fd67d663aba08a56c2c88fa8c5f2427`

Answer (score 0):

I've started working on a fixed-point math library for solidity. It's open source (apache 2) and you're invited to use and contribute. This library can solve your problem by providing a set of basic math functions such as log, power, root, etc., that use fixed point decimal numbers of the kind customarily used for ERC20 tokens and automatic market makers.

Please find the code here:
https://github.com/extraterrestrial-tech/fixidity

It's low on documentation right now, so please contact me if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Improved [answer of Mikhail Vladimirov](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/32900/3032) by optimizing `mostSignificantBit` method. Now `log2` costs **25K** gas instead of **30K** gas:

```
function mostSignificantBit(uint256 x) pure public returns (uint8 r) {
    uint t;
    if ((t = (x >> 128)) > 0) { x = t; r += 128; }
    if ((t = (x >> 64)) > 0) { x = t; r += 64; }
    if ((t = (x >> 32)) > 0) { x = t; r += 32; }
    if ((t = (x >> 16)) > 0) { x = t; r += 16; }
    if ((t = (x >> 8)) > 0) { x = t; r += 8; }
    if ((t = (x >> 4)) > 0) { x = t; r += 4; }
    if ((t = (x >> 2)) > 0) { x = t; r += 2; }
    if ((t = (x >> 1)) > 0) { x = t; r += 1; }
}
```

Comment: This sounds doubtful to me.  Function `log_2` calls `mostSignificantBit` only once, and my variant of `mostSignificantBit` consumes about 2K gas in worst case (Solidity 0.5.10 with optimizations).  Your variant consumes 830 gas (after adding `require (x > 0)`).  So, improvement should be about 1.2K gas, not 75K.  BTW, I optimized `mostSignificantBit` and now it costs 742 gas in worst case.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov sorry, fixed estimation of original code to be 30K gas.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed an approximation, so this works well for me:

```
    function log10(uint256 x) private pure returns(uint8) {
      uint8 r=0;
      do {
        x/=10;
        if(0==x)break;
        r++;
      } while (true);
      return r;
    }
```