# Get order of magnitude of an integer in solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, integers

**What is a way of getting the order of magnitude of an integer (or float) in a solidity contract?**

e.g. such that

```
MyContract.getOrderMag(2564)   returns 3
MyContract.getOrderMag(987)   returns 2
MyContract.getOrderMag(2.3e76)   returns 76
```

Ideally in the least gas using way possible...

Here's what I have:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract Magger {  
    function getOrderMag(int256 input) constant returns (int256){
        int counter=0;
        int temp = input;
        while((temp/10)>1){
            temp = temp/10;
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work with negative numbers or, as pointed out by @RichardHorrocks, when input is 10.

Comment: Related: [What's the most efficient way to check if a number is a power of ten in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/96423/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-check-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-ten-in-solidity).

Answer (score 2):

Just thinking about this a bit more...

Your code takes a (signed) `int256` as input. The maximum (absolute) value of this is around `1e+76`, which would equate to 76 cycles of the `while` loop, each composed of multiple instructions.

In such cases it would probably be cheaper to use a [logarithmic method](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8110/52) - i.e. take the log<sub>10</sub> of the input and ignore any fractional parts. (I say "probably" - I haven't checked.)

It will depend on the what values you expect `input` to usually take, and how quickly the logarithm algorithm converges on an answer.

Comment: Edit: I'd said "unsigned" instead of "signed"...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it. There is probably significant scope for improvement. I would accept any answer that uses less gas:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;
contract Magger {  

    function getOrderMag(int256 input) constant returns (int256){
        int counter=0;
        if (input<0){
            input=input*-1;
        }
            while((input/10)>=1){
                input = input/10;
                counter++;
            }

        return counter;
}
}
```

Comment: As it currently stands, if `input` is 10, then `counter` is 0 instead of 1 (because of the `while` condition).

Comment: You could just remove the `temp` variable and use `input` in the calculation.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Thanks. Yes it's a bit broken; also doesn't work with negative numbers. Going to delete answer an post in edited question.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks attempted to fix

Comment: Looks good :) I've added another answer that considers the size of the input - it may or may not be relevant, depending on how big you think the input will normally be.

Answer (score 1):

```solidity
function magnitude (uint x) public pure returns (uint) {
  require (x > 0);

  uint a = 0;
  uint b = 77;

  while (b > a) {
    uint m = a + b + 1 >> 1;
    if (x >= pow10 (m)) a = m;
    else b = m - 1;
  }

  return a;
}

function pow10 (uint x) private pure returns (uint) {
    uint result = 1;
    uint y = 10;
    while (x > 0) {
      if (x % 2 == 1) {
        result *= y;
        x -= 1;
      } else {
        y *= y;
        x >>= 1;
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This implementation uses bisection and exponentiation by squaring algorithms, has O(ln^2 n) complexity and consumes about 6.5K gas.  Though, it seems that O(n) approach as suggested by @atomh33ls is cheaper.