# How to assign to negative numbers in yul?

Tags: assembly, solidity-0.8.x

Take this code snippet:

```
function powOfTen(uint256 x) internal pure returns (int256 result) {
    assembly {
        switch x
        case 1 { result := -18 }
    }
}
```

Which doesn't compile:

```
ParserError: Literal or identifier expected.
   --> contracts/PRBMath.sol:352:32:
    |
352 |             case 1 { result := -18 }
    |
```

How can I assign to a negative number in yul?

Comment: Is your question "how to assing to negative numbers in yul inside a switch statement" or why do you have such weird switch there :)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I guess he wants to test the function quickly, but probably I'm wrong! ;)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I didn't know that assignment works differently in switch statements. In fact, I am quite new to yul and assembly. See [this Q&A](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/96423/24693) for the full context of why I wanted to use switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to use [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation to use signed integers in yul, since that's the way EVM understand them:

There are some comments about Two's Complement in the Solidity docs:

- [Two’s Complement / Underflows / Overflows](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/security-considerations.html?#two-s-complement-underflows-overflows)
- [Explicit Conversions](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?#explicit-conversions)

So, solving your doubt:

`-15` is represented as: `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1`

`-3` is represented as: `0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffd`

```
function powOfTen(uint256 x) public pure returns (int256 result) {
    assembly {
        switch x
        case 1 { result := 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1 }
        case 2 { result := 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffd }
    }
}
```

I've modified the function from `internal` to `public` if you want to test it on Remix.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @alberto's solution is to use the [sub](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/yul.html#evm-dialect) instruction:

```
function powOfTen(uint256 x) internal pure returns (int256 result) {
    assembly {
        switch x
        case 1 { result := sub(0, 18) }
    }
}
```

The nice thing about this is that it's cleaner, while still paying the same amount of gas when compiling with the optimizer enabled. Credits to [Gitter](https://gitter.im/ethereum/solidity) user @hrkrshnn for telling me about this approach.