# Natural logarithm in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I need to consider the natural logarithm of the numbers in my contract. The numbers range from 1 to 10^25.
Does anyone have ideas on how best to implement this?

Comment: See my [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/97534/24693) and my library [PRBMath](https://github.com/hifi-finance/prb-math).