# How does Uniswap v3's logarithm library (TickMath.sol) work?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, assembly

I want to calculate logarithm of a non-standard base at low gas cost. First thought is to use change of base rule with [`log2()` fixed point methods mentioned in this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8086/logarithm-math-operation-in-solidity/32900#32900).

However [Uniswap v3 core has custom code](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/f03155670ec1667406b83a539e23dcccf32a03bc/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol#L61) for log to the base √1.0001. It has assembly level optimizations which I'm trying to understand. However implementation is opaque and not well documented.

As per my understanding:

1. First find MSB: first set of assembly code probably does this. Why is `r` needed?
2. Use MSB to get log2: What does the second set of assembly do after `log2` is found?
3. Change of base rule: What is the significance of `255738958999603826347141` in `log_2 * 255738958999603826347141`?
4. What is the significance of subtracting `3402992956809132418596140100660247210` for `tickLow` and adding `291339464771989622907027621153398088495` for `tickHi`?

##### [TickMath.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/TickMath.sol)

```
    /// @notice Calculates the greatest tick value such that getRatioAtTick(tick) <= ratio
    /// @dev Throws in case sqrtPriceX96 < MIN_SQRT_RATIO, as MIN_SQRT_RATIO is the lowest value getRatioAtTick may
    /// ever return.
    /// @param sqrtPriceX96 The sqrt ratio for which to compute the tick as a Q64.96
    /// @return tick The greatest tick for which the ratio is less than or equal to the input ratio
    function getTickAtSqrtRatio(uint160 sqrtPriceX96) internal pure returns (int24 tick) {
        // second inequality must be < because the price can never reach the price at the max tick
        require(sqrtPriceX96 >= MIN_SQRT_RATIO && sqrtPriceX96 < MAX_SQRT_RATIO, 'R');
        uint256 ratio = uint256(sqrtPriceX96) << 32;

        uint256 r = ratio;
        uint256 msb = 0;

        assembly {
            let f := shl(7, gt(r, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(6, gt(r, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(5, gt(r, 0xFFFFFFFF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(4, gt(r, 0xFFFF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(3, gt(r, 0xFF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(2, gt(r, 0xF))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := shl(1, gt(r, 0x3))
            msb := or(msb, f)
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            let f := gt(r, 0x1)
            msb := or(msb, f)
        }

        if (msb >= 128) r = ratio >> (msb - 127);
        else r = ratio << (127 - msb);

        int256 log_2 = (int256(msb) - 128) << 64;

        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(63, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(62, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(61, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(60, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(59, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(58, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(57, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(56, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(55, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(54, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(53, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(52, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(51, f))
            r := shr(f, r)
        }
        assembly {
            r := shr(127, mul(r, r))
            let f := shr(128, r)
            log_2 := or(log_2, shl(50, f))
        }

        int256 log_sqrt10001 = log_2 * 255738958999603826347141; // 128.128 number

        int24 tickLow = int24((log_sqrt10001 - 3402992956809132418596140100660247210) >> 128);
        int24 tickHi = int24((log_sqrt10001 + 291339464771989622907027621153398088495) >> 128);

        tick = tickLow == tickHi ? tickLow : getSqrtRatioAtTick(tickHi) <= sqrtPriceX96 ? tickHi : tickLow;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. First find MSB: first set of assembly code probably does this. Why is
>    r needed?

You are correct, this part of assembly is looking for the MSB that will serve as an initial integer approximation for the log 2 variable. the `r` variable is needed as a temporary variable in order to preserve the `ratio` variable, if you only cared about the first assembly block, you could use `ratio` directly and get a perfectly valid MSB.

> 2. Use MSB to get log2: What does the second set of assembly do after log2 is found?

With the MSB of a `number` you get an approximate value of `log_2(number)` as an integer. For example :

`log_2(127) = 6.98868468677` : MSB is 6

`log_2(128) = 7` : MSB is 7

`log_2(129) = 7.01122725542` : MSB is 7

Basically with MSB = x you know that `log_2(value)` is `< MSB + 1` and `>= MSB` but you don't know exactly where it is in between those values.

When dealing with financial data, you can understand why computing the decimal part is absolutely mandatory. This is what this second block of assembly does, refining the integer `log_2` approximation to account for the decimal part up to 14 bits of precision.

> 3. Change of base rule: What is the significance of 255738958999603826347141 in log_2 * 255738958999603826347141?

Those magic numbers are always just a mathematical expression that ends up being constant. In this case this is a change of base from `2` to `sqrt(1.0001)`.

`log_(sqrt(1.0001)(number) = log_2(number) / log_2(sqrt(1.0001))`

you can rewrite `log_2(sqrt(1.0001))` as : `log_(sqrt(1.0001)(sqrt(1.0001) / log_(sqrt(1.0001)(2)` which translates to : `1 / log_(sqrt(1.0001)(2)`

so :

`log_(sqrt(1.0001)(number) = log_2(number) * log_(sqrt(1.0001)(2)`

Now `log_(sqrt(1.0001)(2))` is a constant : 13863.63...

And a previous line transformed the MSB to a  Q64 fixed point number.

```
int256 log_2 = (int256(msb) - 128) << 64;
```

We now want the approximation as a Q128 fixed point number as per the comment. So we need to left shift by 64 or multiply by `2 ** 64`, those are equivalent.

it turns out that `log_(sqrt(1.0001))(2) * 2 ** 64` equals : 255738958999603826347141 (with the correct precision)

(I've had trouble to come up to the exact value but I supposed it's because of precision / rounding errors, if you do the reverse path, it's fine)

so :

```
int256 log_sqrt10001 = log_2 * 255738958999603826347141; // 128.128 number
```

is equivalent to :

```
// Not valid code, just for the example

// With power notation
int256 log_sqrt10001 = log_2 * log(sqrt(1.0001), 2) * 2 ** 64;

// With bit shift notation
 int256 log_sqrt10001 = log_2 * log(sqrt(1.0001), 2) << 64;
```

Where `log(sqrt(1.0001), 2)` changes the base and `2 ** 64` changes the format to Q128.

> 4. What is the significance of subtracting 3402992956809132418596140100660247210 when finding tickLow?

I must admit that I did not clearly understand that part in the code so I won't be able to explain it.. I'll edit the answer if I find out !

Comment: I believe tickLow and tickHi operands are Q128.128, which gives `3402992956809132418596140100660247210 = 0.010000497 x 2^128` and `291339464771989622907027621153398088495 = 0.856 x 2^128`.  `tick` should not be fractional, so they try to find the closest whole number tick. The sum of these numbers is less than 1, to avoid skipping of a tick. But why `0.01` and `0.856` and not `0.2` and `0.7`? Not sure. Meaning of these numbers is the final piece.

Comment: Yes it makes sense, then it could be bounds on the error, that would justify picking those exact numbers. Given that the log_2 decimal parts is only refined on 14 bits, some error could slip into it. When switching to Q128 this error is multiplied by 2 ** 64. This could make sense but I don't find those numbers.. I must be making a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Experimentally it looks like `tickLow -= 0.01`, `tickHi += (accuracy_limit + 0.01) = (2^-14 + 0.01) = 0.856`.  An [older commit](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/commit/fccd58f42e6d2af6fa1bda342742b18ec8c0bbd5#diff-1f4e4c1696e7425edc3bd07a992bb1e23d735698d74dc0baf1c7331ba749fa72R134) using 7 digit refinement and `P = 0.01^t` in place of `√P = 0.0001^t` satisfies this condition, i.e. 188609930776236967625146103726555653720 / 2^128 = 0.5542 = 2^-7 / log2(1.01) + 0.01`. I could be wrong though. Awaiting official word at https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-core/issues/500

Comment: I'm not sure to follow with `(2^-14 + 0.01) = 0.856` ?  2^-14 + 0.01 is roughly equal to 0.01 given how small 2^-14 is. Maybe I misunderstood, though.  So you are saying that the rationale for 0.01 is basically that it is an historical value that used to work ?

Comment: Missed out the division. Accuracy limit should be `2^-14 / log2(√1.0001)`, not `2^-14` as mentioned in tickHi. 0.01 could refer to a 1% error margin?

Comment: Ah okay. I'd say the 0.01 is more likely to be an over estimation upper bound. I find it strange to have it come out of nowhere otherwise... why 1% ? why not 1.5 , 3 or else ?